# How can I access member of main form

Tags: c#, class, encapsulation

I am only learning C# and I am trying to make a 2D game.  I am at the stage where I have my Form1 set up with a 'PictureBox' for the player and the start of a player class:

```
class Player
{
    private string _name;
    private int _health;

    internal Player(string name, int health = 100)
    {
        _name = name;
        _health = health;
    }

    int X = 0;

    internal void Draw()
    {
        updateInput();

        Draw();
    }

    internal void updateInput()
    {
        if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Right))
            X = 1;
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Left))
            X = -1;
        else
            X = 0; 
    }
}
```

There is a PictureBox "pb_play" which contains the character's sprite on the main form.  I tried setting its access modifier to public but that did not help.   I want to change the position of the character by whatever the X value becomes.  So I was trying to essentially access that member of the form the class.

I was attempting to do this inside the draw method, so it would update the input, then after that it would set the position, and then repeat the Draw method, looping constantly.

If there is a better way though, feel free to educate me.  How can I fix this?

EDIT: Okay, I moved the methods into the UI, as mentioned by a comment.  Here is what I have, but the sprite refuses to move:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Draw();
    }

    int X = 0;

    internal void Draw()
    {
        updateInput();

        pb_play.Location = new Point((pb_play.Location.X + X), 0);

        Draw();
    }

    internal void updateInput()
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Right))
            X = 5;
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Left))
            X = -5;
        else
            X = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an event handler somewhere that triggers the method updateInput?

Comment: It's good you're thinking about this. The correct way to do this is not to make the class update the UI, but rather for the UI to consult the class for what state it needs to represent. The class should be as agnostic of the UI and input method as possible.

Comment: looking at the code looks like you're going to be caught in an endless loop am I missing something here..?

Comment: @MethodMan No, but a `StackOverflowException` will happen pretty quickly.

Comment: I updated it with "I was attempting to do this inside the draw method, so it would update the input, then after that it would set the position, and then repeat the Draw method, looping constantly."

Comment: @DavidG that's exactly what I was getting at..

Answer (score 0):

I used a timer to fix the issue:

```
internal void Draw()
    {
        pb_play.Location = new Point((pb_play.Location.X + X), (pb_play.Location.Y + Y));
    }

    internal void updateInput()
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Right))
            X = 1;
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Left))
            X = -1;
        else
            X = 0;

        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up))
            Y = -1;
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down))
            Y = 1;
        else
            Y = 0;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateInput();
        Draw();
    }
```